# Simple Example : Setting attributes by iterating

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
    $(function(){

        var els = [];

        var m = $("#container");
        m.attr({"style" : "width:50%;"});

        $(".grid").each(function(e){
            els.push(this);
        });

        var n = els[3];
        n.attr({"style" : "width:50%;"}) //error
    });
```

Hello, I am fairly new to DOM manipulating. I am wondering why the JQuery above returns [Object][Object] for **var m**, but returns [Object][HTMLDivElement] for **var n**.

Because of this behavior I cannot use statements such as **n.attr(*args*)**.

```
TypeError: n.attr is not a function
```

Ultimately, I would like to store each *.grid* element in an array, and iterate over them, setting attributes as I go.

To be more exact, I have a 6x3 grid of div elements, and each time the page loads, they are given a random **animation-duration** because they are animated to fade in and out of view.

Why can I not use *n.attr()*?

Comment: `m` is the jQuery object. `n` is the `DOM` element you can call `jQuery()` again with `n` as argument to use `.attr()` `$(n).attr({"style" : "width:50%;"})`

Comment: I know that I answered my own question : Because it's an [Object][HTMLDivElement] not an [Object][Object]. But why is this the case? I thought the elements were being acquired in the same manner; one just happens to be an element of an array...

Comment: The array is not the issue. A `DOM` element is not the same as a jQuery object where the underlying `DOM` element is a property of that object

Comment: I posted that comment at the same time you did. Thank you, it worked

Comment: It's these subtle yet jarringly discernible differences that make JS/JQ such a pain to work with O.o

Comment: Note, jQuery is JavaScript. You can use [`DOM`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) methods to achieve the expected result without jQuery

Answer (score 2):

That's because `this` inside the `.each()` loop is the actual DOM element, not the jQuery object. If you want the items in your array to be jQuery objects you need to wrap them in one yourself:

```
els.push($(this));
```

Alternatively, you can just wrap the DOM element at the time you are accessing it:

```
var n = $(els[3]);
```

From [jQuery .each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

> More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current
>   DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.

and

> To access a jQuery object instead of the regular DOM element, use
>   `$( this )`

Comment: Interesting, and a pretty cool example of an instance in which one might use `this` in a selection.

Answer (score 0):

A `DOM` element is not a jQuery object. `n` is an array of `DOM` elements, not jQuery objects which have a `DOM` element as a property. You can achieve the same result using `DOM` methods without jQuery

```
onload = function() {

    var m = document.getElementById("container");

    m.style.width = "50%";

    var els = document.querySelectorAll(".grid");

    var n = els[3];

    n.style.width = "50%";

}
```